# cannot run background services on Lava Iris X1

Tags: android, service, background

had tested on other devices i.e Sony and Samsung, running fine but my background services are not running in lava iris x1. Is there any security setting or any other setting blocking this? there is no any antivirus installed, its fresh and new device set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lava and others (oppo, vivo, honor, etc.) only allow background services for some whitelisted apps by default. For your background service to run you need to ask the user to enable `autoStart` from Settings.